# UWP/XAML programmatically click a button with UI animation

Tags: c#, user-interface, button, uwp, uwp-xaml

I try to make a NumPad similar to the one in the standard Win10 Calculator App.

I implemented a function where the user can press a number on the hardware Keyboard and it will press a button programmatically. To get the number is no problem but I also want to start an animation on the software NumPad like the one in the Win10 calculator.

How can I start that animation by code?

[NumPadAnimation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyNCu.gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I start that animation by code?

You could start the storyboard(the animation) by calling the the [Begin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/motion/storyboarded-animations) method of the Storyboard.

Please read [Storyboarded animations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/motion/storyboarded-animations) for more information.

By the way, the [MS calculator](https://github.com/Microsoft/calculator) is now open source. You could check its source code to learn what you want.

Comment: Thanks, that is (the profressional way) what I'm looking for. If somebody else will read this, there is also an easy way - change the background brush of the button async for around 100ms.The effect is almost the same but there are problems for example if dark mode is enabled.